# how to hide a commands.Custom in kendo?

Tags: javascript, c#, kendo-ui, telerik

I am building a partial view, where I have to hide a button depending on a value from the main view, the columns hides them well, but when hiding the button it does not work.

I have the following function

```
function onSelect(e) {    
gridEstudiantesShowHide(false);
if ($('input[name="hd_idServicio"]').val($("#ddlServicios").val()) != "") {       

    if ($("#ddlServicios").val().split("#")[4] === "0") {            
        var grid = $("#Grid").data("kendoGrid");
        grid.hideColumn(4);
    }
    else {
        var grid = $("#Grid").data("kendoGrid");
        grid.showColumn(4);
       
    }
    if ($("#ddlServicios").val().split("#")[2] == "4" || $("#ddlServicios").val().split("#")[2] == "9") {
        var grid = $("#Grid").data("kendoGrid");
        grid.showColumn(5);
    }
    else {
        var grid = $("#Grid").data("kendoGrid");
        grid.hideColumn(5);
    }
    if ($("#ddlServicios").val().split("#")[3] == "1") {
        var grid = $("#Grid").data("kendoGrid");
        grid.hideColumn(3);
   
        columns: [
            { field: "name" },
             { command: [{ name: "AsignarGrupo", visible: false}] }                               
        ]

    }
    else {
        console.log("Muestra botón");
        var grid = $("#Grid").data("kendoGrid");
        grid.showColumn(3); 
   { command: [{ name: "AsignarGrupo", visible: false}] }   


    }

}
else {
   
}
```

it only works when hiding columns, and I have read all the dojo documentation to no avail.

Someone could help me?

Comment: Difficult to help you with your example. Please create a Minimal, Reproducible Example (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

The property `visible` in the column's command expects a function which have to return a boolean, so you can do this in your column definition:

```
{ command: [{ name: "AsignarGrupo", visible: function(dataItem) { return $("\\#ddlServicios").val().split("\\#")[3] == "1"; } }] }
```

Demo:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <title>Kendo UI Snippet</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2021.1.330/styles/kendo.default-v2.min.css"/>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2021.1.330/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <select id="ddlServicios">
    <option value="1#1#1#1">Opt 1</option>
  </select>
<div id="grid"></div>
<script>
  
$("#grid").kendoGrid({
  columns: [
    { field: "name" },
    { command: "destroy" }, // displays the built-in "destroy" command
    { command: [{ name: "test", visible: function(dataItem) { return $("\\#ddlServicios").val().split("\\#")[3] == "1"; } }] }
  ],
  editable: true,
  dataSource: [ { name: "Jane Doe" } ]
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

[Dojo](https://dojo.telerik.com/eXUgeJiJ)